# View full instagram profile picture php script assistance?

Tags: php, instagram

I have a wordpress website with a plugin that when you enter in someone's instagram username, it'll show you it in full size. Recently Instagram changed their ways so it no longer works. I found one way that does work, but I'm not sure how to put it into a `PHP` code.

Here's the tutorial I found:

Get the **userId** from `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?_a=1`

and get the **profile pic** url from 
`https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{user_id}/info/`

So basically what you do is you go to the first link with the username in there, eg: `https://www.instagram.com/JaredGoff/?__a=1`

Then you look for the **owner id** which should be near the top of the page, eg: `"owner":{"id":"35192126"}`

You copy that string of numbers then go to that second link with the id pasted in, eg: `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/35192126/info/`

You go to that link and find the `scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com` link with the highest resolution. It's this one here: `https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/0d671bfd2996c4f750e3022e92c2dffa/5B735E9F/t51.2885-19/s640x640/26073736_1686768224695889_7419777864670642176_n.jpg`

Then I want to display that image.

here is my current code that doesn't work:

```
function instagram(){

    $instagram_source = wp_remote_get("https://www.instagram.com/" . $_REQUEST['insta_username'] . "/?__a=1");
    $instagram_source = json_decode($instagram_source['body'], true);

    $profile_pic = $instagram_source['user']['profile_pic_url_hd'];
    $profile_pic = str_replace('/s150x150/', '/', $profile_pic);

    if(strlen($profile_pic) > 0){

        echo '<img src="' . $profile_pic . '">';
    }
    else{

        echo 'Profile does not exist.';
    }


    wp_die();
}

function wpb_load_widget() {

    register_widget( 'wpb_widget' );
}

class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('instaimage',
            __('Instagram Profile Image', 'Instalab'),
        array( 'description' => __( '', 'Instalab'),));
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        echo '<form onsubmit="download_image(); return false;">
            <input placeholder="Enter instagram username" type="text" id="insta_username" name="insta_username">
            <a class="button is-primary" id="insta_submit">Show</a>
          </form><br>
          <div id="insta_image" style="width:100%;"></div>
          ';

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code (I know not the most efficient, but it works):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.instagram.com/$name/?__a=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json=json_decode($result);
$insta_id = $json->graphql->user->id;
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,"https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/$insta_id/info/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);
$json=json_decode($result);
$image_url = $json->user->hd_profile_pic_url_info->url;
if($image_url) {
  echo '<img src="'.$image_url.'"/>';
}
```

Comment: I put it into my site but it still says profile doesn't exist. Did I plug it in correctly?: https://pastebin.com/3jyYMyxC

Comment: do i need to get api account for this ? or will it work without htat ?